# (theoretical) doubt in Gauss law

Tags: electromagnetism

Let us assume the universe is filled with positive charges. At a particular point, all the positive charged particles will be symmetrical. Now, we assume a sphere of radius r (finite) as our Gaussian surface. And now we apply Gauss law.

According to Gauss law the electric flux through the sphere will be some finite value as it contains some positive charge. But by symmetry the electric field through the Gaussian and hence electric flux will be zero. Hence contradictory!

Comment: if unable to understand comment....please.

Comment: Wouldn't this fit better for physics?

Comment: *"Let us assume the universe filled with positive charge"* may be an inaccurate assumption?

Comment: The net charge of the universe on a macroscopic scale is roughly zero.

Comment: To expand, Gravitational force is several orders of magnitude weaker than Coulomb force. If the universe had any significant net charge it would be quite evident in macroscopic dynamics of the universe

Comment: Nothing to do with electronic design. Question should be closed.

Answer (score 2):

Gauß' law says that a charge inside a volume generates a total flux through the surface of that volume. It also implies that external fields do not contribute to this flux. Simply saying: external flux will enter the volume on one side, and leave on the other, resulting in no *total* flux.

Now, you're speaking about the universe and finding its center, which is a story on its own. Let's assume a sphere with uniform charge distribution \$\rho\$. And we will use spheres as volumes / surfaces of radius r as it's a symmetrical problem. Then, you get

$$E\cdot 4\pi r^2=\frac{1}{\varepsilon_0}\rho\cdot \frac{4}{3}\pi r^3\quad\Rightarrow\quad E=\frac{\rho}{3\varepsilon_0}\cdot r$$

This is the E-field generated by the uniform charge distribution enclosed by the sphere, directly at the surface. For an infinite sphere, the field will be infinite, too.

Another one:
Think of a sphere or radius R and charge Q. Outside the sphere, the field is

$$E\cdot 4\pi r^2=\frac{1}{\varepsilon_0}Q\quad\Rightarrow\quad E=\frac{Q}{4\pi\varepsilon_0}\cdot \frac{1}{r^2}\quad for \quad r\ge R$$

Inside, you have to replace the full charge by the charge enclosed by Gauß' surface, the fraction is defined by the volume:

$$\frac{Q'}{Q}=\frac{\frac43 \pi r^3}{\frac43 \pi R^3}\quad\Rightarrow\quad Q'=\frac{r^3}{R^3}Q$$
and so

$$E=\frac{Q}{4\pi\varepsilon_0}\cdot \frac{r}{R^3}\quad for \quad r\le R$$

Finally, I don't see any problems with Gauß. I guess you just forget that point about external fields.